# BaseOn style inside DataTemplate bugs xaml designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, basedon

Look at screenshot:

[image]

There are 2 `TextBlock` with custom style which is `BasedOn` on default style.

One inside `DataTemplate` **all time shows error**.

Despite the fact what software compiles and run without problem, this is pretty annoying. How can I fix it?

---

Repro:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"></Style>
        </TextBlock.Style></TextBlock>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock"
                               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"></Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: It's because it's in a Datatemplate.

Comment: @ChrisW., correct duplicate, thanks for finding it.

Comment: Eh, I run into that sort of issue all the time too and have to remind myself, it's a pain sometimes and seems like it shouldn't be an issue. Oh well, have a great weekend!

Comment: ...and not sure why you got downvoted but +1 back for it.

Comment: I decide to keep question, because I was blaming `BaseOn`, someone else may too.